# Appending mysql data in an result

Tags: php, mysql

I am having `table member(id, name , email, altEmail, phone, altPhone, date)`.
*id* is unique *1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....520,521*.

```
    id   email  altemail 

    1    2@h.v   2@T.h

    2    3@gy.c    -

    3       -     4@t.c
```

I need output as :

```
id   mail 

 1    2@h.v  

 1    2@T.h

 2    3@gy.c

 3    4@t.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*UNION ALL*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT `id`, `email` mail FROM t WHERE  `email` <> '-'
UNION ALL 
SELECT `id`, `altemail` mail FROM t WHERE  `altemail` <> '-'
ORDER BY `id`
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa228/4)

**Edit for null values**

```
SELECT `id`, `email` mail FROM t WHERE  `email` <> ''  AND `email` IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT `id`, `altemail` mail FROM t WHERE  `altemail` <> '' AND `altemail` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `id`
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db392/2)

Comment: @user3426968 provide your sample dataset here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ so i can see whats wrong with you try ,and for null you can use `WHERE  email <>'' and email is not null`

Comment: Thanks Buddy... hope i would have knowledge like u

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
select id, email as mail from member union select id, altemail from member  order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. for such a great help